Why can't I use input() to get an object?
I created a list of Animals. Then I ask the user, What are you? When he answers, I can't get the program to recognize it in the list.
class Animal:
    def make_sound(self):
        pass  # This is an abstract method

class Dog(Animal):
    def make_sound(self):
        print("Woof!")

dog = Dog()

animals = [dog, cat, duck]

what = input("What are you? ")

if what in animals : what.make_sound()  
else : print("it's not in the list")

what = dog
if what in animals : what.make_sound()  
else : print("it's not in the list")

Here is the output:
What are you? dog
it's not in the list
try it this way, what = dog
Woof!


This question is similar to: How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You must remember that input() always returns a str, so that means you could just have a dict to map from that to one of your objects:
class Dog():
    def make_sound(self):
        print("Woof!")

class Cat():
    def make_sound(self):
        print("Meow")

class Duck():
    def make_sound(self):
        print("Quack!")

dog = Dog()
cat = Cat()
duck = Duck()

animals = {'dog':dog, 'cat':cat, 'duck':duck}

what = input("What are you? ")

if what in animals: 
    animals[what].make_sound()  
else:
    print("it's not in the list")

what = 'dog'
if what in animals: 
    animals[what].make_sound()  
else:
    print("it's not in the list")

Example session:
What are you? duck
Quack!
Woof!


Instead of using if/else you could do try/except, it's considered more Pythonic.
